# C# Graphics.FillRectangle not working at all

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

The code below won't work no matter how many times I press the button, it's really annoying me

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(600, 800);
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(screen);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0));
        gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 600, 800);
        gfx.Dispose();
        brush.Dispose();
        screen.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: you didn't tell it where to draw.  try using `gfx = this.CreateGraphics();` after you create gfx from the bitmap (this will draw on your form).  a better route is to use paint events on a control though

Comment: _"try using `gfx = this.CreateGraphics();`"_ -- no, do **not** do this. No correct Winforms code, especially not code written by someone new to the API, will ever call the `CreateGraphics()` method. **Do** use the `Paint` event, and draw your graphics into the `e.Graphics` object passed to the event handler.

Comment: Get rid of `screen.Dispose();` and assign that Bitmap to something that can display it...like a PictureBox maybe?  `pictureBox1.Image = screen;`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ever draw your bitmap to the screen. You could do this like that:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(600, 800);
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(screen);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0));
    gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 600, 800);
    CreateGraphics().DrawImage(screen, 0, 0);
    gfx.Dispose();
    brush.Dispose();
    screen.Dispose();
}
```

However you shouldn't use that, as it prevents optimal DoubleBuffering to work and as the changes are erased whenever the paint event is fired, and therefore isn't good practice.

Instead you should handle the Paint event (To do this, go to the designer (press F7 in the code behind), select your form, open the properties window (Press F4), select the events tab (click onto the lightning bolt) and double click into the field right to *Paint*):

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(600, 800);
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(screen);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0));
    gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 600, 800);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(screen, 0, 0);
    gfx.Dispose();
    brush.Dispose();
    screen.Dispose();
}
```

However it's not recommendable to use a bitmap in that case, as you don't have much being displayed - instead you should directly draw to the graphics of the form:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var gfx = e.Graphics)
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0)))
        gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 600, 800);
}
```

You could notice that I used `using`, which is good practice, as it automatically disposes the objects.

Now all you have to do (you have to do this for both solutions including the handling of the paint event) is to call `Invalidate()` in your button click event handling and set a property that tells the paint method that it is being called because a button got pressed:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_button2Pressed)
        return;
    using (var gfx = e.Graphics)
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0)))
        gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 600, 800);
    _button2Pressed = false;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _button2Pressed = true;
    Invalidate();
}
private bool _button2Pressed;
```

This should do it.

Comment: It throws a exception parameter not valid when I click the button

Comment: What exception is being thrown? And are you sure you handled the events correctly?

Comment: @MaatheGamer And in what solution did the exception get thrown?

Comment: No need for `Refresh`, `Invalidate` is sufficient. Also, the reason you avoid CreateGraphics has nothing to do with double buffering. It has to do with the fact that your changes get instantly erased as soon as the Paint event runs, which it does frequently and in ways that your app can't control.